# HAXM on OS X keeps on disappearing

Tags: macos, android-studio, haxm

I have recently moved my android development environment on OS X, using El Capitan. Everything is working as expected. The only problem i find is that after every time I restart my PC the HAXM gets disappeared from '/dev' and Android Studio Reports it while starting an emulator using the HAXM.

When I go to extras in Android SDK folder and try to install, it says that the same is already installed and if continue, it will be reinstalled. I continue to install. After which every thing works fine, till next reboot of the system.

Can anyone please tell me, how to resolve the issue. It is not a big task to reinstall HAXM, but it is really annoying.

Comment: I am also having this problem...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured this one out: when upgrading from HAXM 1.1.4 to 1.1.5 on El Capitan, the installation path moves from `/System/Library` to `/Library`. However, the in-place upgrade script shipped by the HAXM installer doesn't handle this perfectly, which leaves things in a funky state. It is for this reason that the HAXM page says:

> Before installing HAXM 1.1.5, the previous version (1.1.4 and below) must be uninstalled using:
>
> sudo /System/Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/uninstall.sh

If your installation is already broken because you didn't uninstall 1.1.4 before installing 1.1.5, the following steps worked for me:

- Uninstall 1.1.5 from its new path by running `/Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/uninstall.sh` with `sudo`
- Remove left-over 1.1.4 files (specifically for me the key was to remove `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.intel.haxm.plist` although there may be more files left over in `/System/Library` for other people)
- Reinstall 1.1.5 the normal way

Comment: Thanks Evan, let me try that tonight. I will update you on this.

Comment: as you said that the installation was already broken, so I performed the cleanup as you suggested and you know what? It worked after a restart. here are the commands I used:  `sudo /Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/uninstall.sh` and 
      `sudo rm /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.intel.haxm.plist`