# Android Emulator not starting and launching the app in Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I am frequently getting error in emulator starting and launching.

I am using MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13 (17A405)

Rarely creating new emulator working but not all the time.

The error I am getting is added as image.[image]

Comment: Happened with me once too. Ended up having to make a new one, not sure why it happened though

Comment: Now I have created new Emulator three times, still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Recreating emulators did not resolve this for me. This link proposes to have a solution. I have not tried it yet though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981033/emulator-not-starting-after-updating-to-android-studio-3-0

Comment: Thanks @running-codebase. I have fixed it. It is because of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused because of less RAM. My total RAM is 8GB. I configured Android studio with some settings in vm virtual options to increase the performance. With that settings, the Ram used by Android studio is 4GB. Additionally few other apps are also accessing the RAM and the emulator didn't get enough RAM to run. So it crashed.

If this issues comes at your end,

1. Try restarting the emulator.
2. Try restarting the Android studio.
3. Try to create new emulator and start.
4. kill adb and start back again.
5. Still the issue exist, might be because of RAM. If the RAM is ok to run, then restart your system will fix the issue.