# Android Studio & Big Sur emulator crash on start HVF error?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, macos-big-sur, haxm

I have a fresh Android Studio installation (4.1.3) and am having a really hard time getting any emulator to run.

I started off with Android Emulator 30.5.4. This alone did not work, most of the time qemu would lock up on launch (no window, just a frozen icon in the dock). Next I installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) 7.6.5. This would result in the emulator crashing every time I tried to launch it from the manager.

I toggled graphics from Automatic to both Hardware and Software... yielding the same results.

I then tried what this post suggested: [Emulator not starting after updating to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981033/emulator-not-starting-after-updating-to-android-studio#answer-47374723). Uninstalled HAXM 7.6.5, installed 7.6.6 manually from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases. Again hit another roadblock.

I have also tried some older build tools (31.0.0), various SDK platforms (Oreo, Nougat, Q), toggling advancedFeatures.ini (HVF, HAXM).

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Would really love to get an emulator running as I don't have a hardware device.

```
~/.android/avd/Nexus_6P_API_25.avd » ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_6P_API_25                          
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.4.0 (build_id 7243153) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
HVF error: HV_ERROR
qemu-system-i386: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
qemu-system-i386: Back to HAX accelerator
added library ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
cannot add library ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed
added library ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a duplicate. A workaround is here: [Android Emulator 30.4.5 not working on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455173/android-emulator-30-4-5-not-working-on-macos)

macOS 11.3 seems to be the common thread. Side note that was interesting: when I generated my crash reports to send, the GPU would render as UNKNOWN. This is on a 2018 MBP i9 + AMD 560X

Comment: Another thing to try if this doesn’t work involves creating a fake entitlements: https://medium.com/m/global-identity?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flevelup.gitconnected.com%2Fhow-to-fix-android-studio-emulator-issue-the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-killed-db74cb02a359