# Error launching Emulator AVD Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I get this warning when I launch the emulator.

```
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
```

What happens is that the emulator pops up but the screen of the phone stays black. I've waited for half an hour but it just stays black.

I have enabled virtualisation from the bios. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and my CPU processor is AMD.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817118/android-emulator-system-images-and-amd-processor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464164/haxm-and-lollipop

Comment: FTR [this seems to be the relevant bugreport](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37076174)

Answer (score 4):

Probably your CPU doesn't support SSE3 (or you don't have haxm installed), therefore the emulator won't work in x86 mode. Try to use Genymotion or use an ARM emulator.

Comment: Annoyingly, using the ARM emulator may be the best option - HAXM has caused me nothing but problems (Core 2 Quad).

Comment: HAXM working fine at me with the new emulator. However genymotion is  still an option :)