# There is some trouble while starting the Android emulator(Ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I starting the Android emulator in AVD manager in Android Studio, it gives my the below **Error** message:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work.
```

And I change the Graphic options in here:
[image]

to

[image]

and it give the below Warnning message to me:

```
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
```

**I have searched many questions but still can resolve this matter!!!**

**the Host CPU of my desktop is AMD Athlon™ II X4 640, it has SSE3 instructions.**

How can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911302/cannot-launch-emulator-on-linux-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: But I cannot resolve **the second** problem!!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664951/error-launching-emulator-avd-android-studio

Comment: I guess you will have to go with an alternative

Comment: But My Desktop's CPU supports SSE3,The question given to me to read cannot help me to fix it.

Comment: I just want to use the AVD in Linux.....I don't want to get more problem.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Requirements it needs intel processor

Comment: maybe look at genymotion

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/q/33664951/5241603

Comment: It says AMD processor with support for AMD Virtualization™ (AMD-V™) could make AVD work on Linux.

Comment: Did you try to enable it in your BIOS/UEFI? If i'm not wrong sometimes it comes disabled by default

Comment: Yeah,I have already enalbled it in my BIOS/UEFI,but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope haxm is not installed in your system. Try arm emulator instead of haxm.

Also a small note: Latest Android Studio will not support 32 bit systems and if you still want to use then you have to download build-tools 23.0.1

Comment: My system is 64 bit, Not 32,And haxm isn't just for intel?