# When i Connect genymotion and Android studio.Its show error

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

When I connect genymotion and Android studio it shows the following error.

```
Hax is enabled
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 POPCNT
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
Could not load func glBindFramebuffer
Could not load func glGenFramebuffers
Could not load func glFramebufferTexture2D
Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus
Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers
Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer
Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer
Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers
Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers
Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage
Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer
qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\gfhgf\.android\avd\Nexus_4_API_21.avd/cache.img: could not open disk image C:\Users\gfhgf\.android\avd\Nexus_4_API_21.avd/cache.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\gfhgf\.android\avd\Nexus_4_API_21.avd/cache.img': Invalid argument
```

Please help me. How can I solve this type of problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HAXM and Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464164/haxm-and-lollipop)

Comment: enable your vt-x from bios and disable your antivirus for sometime